# GoogleMaps API v3 - Need help with two "click" event scenarios. Need similar functionality to v2 API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In version 2 of the API the map click event returned an Overlay, LatLng, Overlaylatlng.

I used this to create a generic map event that would either retrieve the coordinates of the Map click event, or return the coordinates of a Marker or other type of Overlay.

Now that API v3 doesn't return the Overlay or Overlaylatlng during the map click event, how can I go about creating a generic "click" event for the map that works if the user clicks on a marker or overlay?  I really don't want to create a click event for each marker I have on my page as I am creating anywhere from a handful to a couple thousand markers.

Also, I had to create a custom ImageMapType in order to display the StreetViewOverlay like we could do in v2 of the API because I couldn't find anywhere that told me how to add the StreetViewOverlay without the pegman icon.  How can I go about retrieving the LatLng coordinates of a click on this overlay type as well?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a click listener to each overlay you add. You can do this in a createMarker function to reduce your code overhead.

Clicks on markers do not trigger a click event on the map at all.